# How to get org.apache.lucene.document.Document after build but before indexing

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'd like to inject my code somewhere in Hibernate Search, where Document object is fully prepared but not indexed yet.
As far as I know, concept Document object is created by [DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/4.3/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/engine/spi/DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java) class. [getDocument](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/4.3/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/engine/spi/DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java#L447) method prepares master fields (Id and _hibernate_class) and then calls [buildDocumentFields](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/4.3/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/engine/spi/DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java#L492), where the classBridge is called. Then it adds all fields on base level (also calling FieldBridge) and adds all [embedded objects](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/4.3/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/engine/spi/DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java#L560) calling recursively [buildDocumentFields](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/4.3/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/engine/spi/DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java#L577). So far is rather clear for me.

For all bridges I got progressively filled Document object. My aim is to get final Document version (witch is returned from [getDocument](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/4.3/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/engine/spi/DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java#L489)) to made some computing before it is provided to indexing engine. Is it possible? What is the simplest way to do it?

btw. I was though about custom IndexManager, but it seems to be too complex for this simple purpose...

Thanks for you time and hope you help.

**Solution:**

I finally decided to implement [IndexManager](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/4.3/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/indexes/spi/IndexManager.java#L47) implementation, extended [DirectoryBasedIndexManager](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/4.3/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/indexes/impl/DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java#L60) and overrided document indexing methods (`performStreamOperation` and `performOperations`).

Below is my code:

```
public class SearchIndexManager extends DirectoryBasedIndexManager
{
    private void processDocument(Document doc)
    {
        if (doc != null && doc.getFields() != null) 
        {
            for (Fieldable field : doc.getFields())
                {/*my job goes here*/};
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void performStreamOperation
    (LuceneWork singleOperation,IndexingMonitor monitor, boolean forceAsync) 
    {
        if (singleOperation != null)
            processDocument(singleOperation.getDocument());
        super.performStreamOperation(singleOperation, monitor, forceAsync);
    }

    @Override
    public void performOperations
    (List<LuceneWork> workList,IndexingMonitor monitor)
    {
        for (LuceneWork lw: workList) 
        {
            if (lw != null)
                processDocument(lw.getDocument());
        }
        super.performOperations(workList, monitor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With versions available today (4.2) this is not possible: you could apply a ClassBridge to edit the Document, but this would be in *alternative* to all other fields.

I would love to add such a feature and think we'll basically redesign the ClassBridge annotation to be applied in this late phase (after Document construction) to allow for this during the works to support Lucene 4.

Please describe what you would expect on a [JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH) feature request; normally I would invite you to propose a patch but in this case we're having many changes in mind already so I think it's best if you could exemplify your use case, ideally with a test. Pseudo-code test is welcome too, since it's just a concept idea.

To avoid waiting for a future release you can indeed use a custom *IndexManager*: it's not complex as the provided ones are designed to be extended, just override the methods you need. Alternatively to the *IndexManager* your could consider implementing a custom *org.hibernate.search.backend.spi.BackendQueueProcessor* by extending the default one (*org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueProcessor*). To keep in mind that we don't keep a backwards compatibility policy for these types as we would for other APIs.

Comment: Finally I used IndexManager - see edit above. Let me know if I missed stg, please :)

Comment: That looks good! I've taken the liberty to remove the log statements as they are not needed for the sake of the example, and the initialize method isn't needed so removed it as well.

Comment: Added https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1348 but not sure it is what you expected.